# Using the UIView-Glow category on UITableViewCell

Tags: uiview, glow, viewdidappear

I'm using the [UIView-Glow](https://github.com/thesecretlab/UIView-Glow) category trying to highlight certain UITableViewCells. But it doesn't work if it's used in *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:*.
I guess it must be used after the certain view appeared on the screen. So, is there a possibility to let certain UITableViewCells glow (even when scrolling the table view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is possibility to let certain UITableViewCells glow with the category file you mentioned. You need to call the category methods in the table view delegate willDisplayCell instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell startGlowing];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the method I was looking for. Still one problem remains: If I reload the tableView the cells get re-used. This results in glows of the wrong cells. It seems that `[cell stopGlowing]` doesn't always show the desired effect when cells get re-used.

Comment: @Norbert have you put the conditional in the willDisplayCell?

Comment: I think so, yes: `if (letItGlow)
    {
        [cell startGlowingWithColor:[UIColor redColor] intensity:0.3f];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell stopGlowing];
    }`

Comment: @Norbert you might need to put further checking whether the view is glowing, e.g. `if [cell glowView]`, in the first place before calling stopGlowing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either: `...else if([cell glowView])
    {
        [cell stopGlowing];
    }` See this [Screenshot](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/914/bildschirmfoto20130603u.png)